# Duplicate symbols on Mac OS X with cmake and gcc47, but not on Linux and Windows

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, linker

I have some code that compiles fine in Linux and Windows but fails in Mac reporting the duplicate symbol error accross different object files.

What does the compiler or linker do different in Mac, that might be the source of error?

Can be this somehow related to the use of templates and inline functions?

I'd like to select part of the code, but I don't know what is causing the error in order to extract the rellevant part of it or build up a MWE.

Also, the headers do have the guards.

On Mac I'm using gcc47 from MacPorts, and on linux I'm using gcc 4.6, in case that makes a difference.

UPDATE:

An example of one of the 130 duplicated symbols:

```
Linking CXX executable train
duplicate symbol maxflow::Graph<int, int, int>::add_tweights(int, int, int) in:
CMakeFiles/train.dir/svm_struct_api.o
CMakeFiles/train.dir/inference.o
```

And an excerpt of the compile line in Linux of `ìnference.cpp` and `svm_struct_api.c`

```
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_struct_api.o
g++    -fopenmp -g -pg -D WITH_PNG -D WITH_OPENMP -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING   -D USE_RAYS3D -D RAYS_MULTITHREADING   -D USE_ITK  -ftemplate-depth-50 -Wall -Wno-deprecated -msse2  -ftemplate-depth-50 -Wall -Wno-deprecated -msse2 -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING  -D USE_LIBDAI -D USE_MAXFLOW  -fopenmp -g -pg -D WITH_PNG -D WITH_OPENMP -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING   -D USE_RAYS3D -D RAYS_MULTITHREADING   -D USE_ITK -O3 -I/home/monso/code/ITK3/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/Review -I/home/monso/code/ITK3/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/gdcm/src -I/home/monso/code/ITK3/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities/gdcm [...] -I/home/monso/code/ITK3/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build -I/home/monso/code/opencv/build -I/home/monso/code/opencv/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/include/opencv -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/core/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/imgproc/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/flann/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/highgui/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/features2d/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/calib3d/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/ml/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/video/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/objdetect/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/contrib/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/nonfree/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/photo/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/legacy/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/gpu/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/softcascade/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/stitching/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/ts/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/videostab/include -I/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/graphCuts -I/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../core -I/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../shaders -I/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/slic -I/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/libsvm-3.0 -I/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/rays3d -I/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/libDAI024/include -I/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/mpir    -o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_struct_api.o -c /home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/svm_struct_api.c

[ 13%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/predict.dir/inference.o
g++    -fopenmp -g -pg -D WITH_PNG -D WITH_OPENMP -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING   -D USE_RAYS3D -D RAYS_MULTITHREADING   -D USE_ITK  -ftemplate-depth-50 -Wall -Wno-deprecated -msse2  -ftemplate-depth-50 -Wall -Wno-deprecated -msse2 -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING  -D USE_LIBDAI -D USE_MAXFLOW  -fopenmp -g -pg -D WITH_PNG -D WITH_OPENMP -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING   -D USE_RAYS3D -D RAYS_MULTITHREADING   -D USE_ITK -O3 -I/home/monso/code/ITK3/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/Review [...] -I/home/monso/code/ITK3/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build -I/home/monso/code/opencv/build -I/home/monso/code/opencv/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/include/opencv -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/core/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/imgproc/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/flann/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/highgui/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/features2d/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/calib3d/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/ml/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/video/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/objdetect/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/contrib/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/nonfree/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/photo/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/legacy/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/gpu/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/softcascade/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/stitching/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/ts/include -I/home/monso/code/opencv/modules/videostab/include -I/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/graphCuts -I/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../core -I/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../shaders -I/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/slic -I/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/libsvm-3.0 -I/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/rays3d -I/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/libDAI024/include -I/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/mpir    -o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/inference.o -c /home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/inference.cpp
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/build/CMakeFiles 14
```

and an excerpt of the building line in Linux

```
Linking CXX executable predict
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/predict.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
g++    -fopenmp -g -pg -D WITH_PNG -D WITH_OPENMP -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING   -D USE_RAYS3D -D RAYS_MULTITHREADING   -D USE_ITK  -ftemplate-depth-50 -Wall -Wno-deprecated -msse2  -ftemplate-depth-50 -Wall -Wno-deprecated -msse2 -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING  -D USE_LIBDAI -D USE_MAXFLOW  -fopenmp -g -pg -D WITH_PNG -D WITH_OPENMP -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING   -D USE_RAYS3D -D RAYS_MULTITHREADING   -D USE_ITK -O3      CMakeFiles/predict.dir/predict.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_struct/svm_struct_common.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_struct/svm_struct_learn.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_light/svm_common.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_light/svm_hideo.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_light/svm_learn.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_struct_api.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_struct_learn_custom.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/constraint_set.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/label_cache.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/inference_globals.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/computeStats.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/globalStats.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/energyParam.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/inference.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/graphInference.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/gi_ICM.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/gi_max.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/gi_martingale.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/gi_MF.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/gi_sampling.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/gi_libDAI.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/gi_maxflow.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/BOF.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/colormap.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/Config.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/Feature.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Cluster.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_ColorHistogram.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Combo.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Gaussian.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Glcm.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Histogram.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_LoadFromFile.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_OrientedHistogram.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Position.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Precomputed.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Test.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/Histogram.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/HistogramND.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/oSVM.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/PixelData.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/Slice3d.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/Slice.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/Slice_P.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/SliceData.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/StatModel.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/Supernode.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/utils.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/libsvm-3.0/svm.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_3dRays.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_CannyStats.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Filter.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_GradientStats.o  -o predict -rdynamic -L/home/monso/code/ITK3/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/bin -L/home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib -L/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/slic/build -L/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/rays3d/build -L/home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/libDAI024/build /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_flann.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_ml.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_photo.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_softcascade.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_ts.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_video.so /home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_videostab.so /home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/slic/build/libsupervoxel.a -lITKIO -lITKStatistics /home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/rays3d/build/librays3d.a /home/monso/code/mito/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/libDAI024/build/libdai.a -lITKNrrdIO -litkgdcm -litkjpeg12 -litkjpeg16 -litkopenjpeg -litkpng -litktiff -litkjpeg8 -lITKSpatialObject -lITKMetaIO -lITKDICOMParser -lITKEXPAT -lITKniftiio -lITKznz -litkzlib -lITKCommon -litksys -litkvnl_inst -litkvnl_algo -litkvnl -litkvcl -litkv3p_lsqr -lpthread -lm -ldl -litkNetlibSlatec -litkv3p_netlib -lm -Wl,-rpath,/home/monso/code/ITK3/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/bin:/home/monso/code/opencv/build/lib 
[...]
[ 50%] Built target predict
```

And in Mac

```
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_struct_api.o
g++    -fopenmp -g -pg -D WITH_PNG -D WITH_OPENMP -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING   -D USE_RAYS3D -D RAYS_MULTITHREADING   -D USE_ITK   -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING  -D USE_LIBDAI -D USE_MAXFLOW  -fopenmp -g -pg -D WITH_PNG -D WITH_OPENMP -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING   -D USE_RAYS3D -D RAYS_MULTITHREADING   -D USE_ITK -O3 -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/Review -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/gdcm/src -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities/gdcm -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities/vxl/core -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities/vxl/vcl -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities/vxl/v3p/netlib -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/vxl/core -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/vxl/vcl -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/vxl/v3p/netlib -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/Numerics/Statistics -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/itkExtHdrs -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/nifti/znzlib -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/nifti/niftilib -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/expat -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities/expat -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities/DICOMParser -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/DICOMParser -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities/NrrdIO -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/NrrdIO -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/MetaIO -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/SpatialObject -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/Numerics/NeuralNetworks -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/Numerics/FEM -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/IO -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/Numerics -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/Common -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/BasicFilters -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/Algorithms -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/include/opencv -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/core/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/imgproc/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/flann/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/highgui/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/features2d/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/calib3d/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/ml/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/video/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/objdetect/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/contrib/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/photo/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/legacy/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/gpu/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/ocl/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/nonfree/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/stitching/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/superres/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/ts/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/videostab/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/graphCuts -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../core -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../shaders -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/slic -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/libsvm-3.0 -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/rays3d -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/libDAI024/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/mpir -I/Users/monso/code/boost_1_51_0    -o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_struct_api.o -c /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/svm_struct_api.c

[ 13%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/predict.dir/inference.o
g++    -fopenmp -g -pg -D WITH_PNG -D WITH_OPENMP -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING   -D USE_RAYS3D -D RAYS_MULTITHREADING   -D USE_ITK   -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING  -D USE_LIBDAI -D USE_MAXFLOW  -fopenmp -g -pg -D WITH_PNG -D WITH_OPENMP -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING   -D USE_RAYS3D -D RAYS_MULTITHREADING   -D USE_ITK -O3 -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/Review -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/gdcm/src -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities/gdcm -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities/vxl/core -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities/vxl/vcl -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities/vxl/v3p/netlib -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/vxl/core -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/vxl/vcl -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/vxl/v3p/netlib -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/Numerics/Statistics -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/itkExtHdrs -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/nifti/znzlib -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/nifti/niftilib -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/expat -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities/expat -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities/DICOMParser -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/DICOMParser -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/Utilities/NrrdIO -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/NrrdIO -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Utilities/MetaIO -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/SpatialObject -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/Numerics/NeuralNetworks -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/Numerics/FEM -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/IO -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/Numerics -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/Common -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/BasicFilters -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/Code/Algorithms -I/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/include/opencv -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/core/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/imgproc/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/flann/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/highgui/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/features2d/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/calib3d/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/ml/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/video/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/objdetect/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/contrib/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/photo/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/legacy/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/gpu/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/ocl/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/nonfree/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/stitching/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/superres/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/ts/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/modules/videostab/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/graphCuts -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../core -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../shaders -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/slic -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/libsvm-3.0 -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/rays3d -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/libDAI024/include -I/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/../../../lib/mpir -I/Users/monso/code/boost_1_51_0    -o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/inference.o -c /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/tools/ssvm/core/inference.cpp
```

And an excerpt of the link line in Mac

```
g++   -Wall -O3 -fopenmp -g -pg -D WITH_PNG -D WITH_OPENMP -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING   -D USE_RAYS3D -D RAYS_MULTITHREADING   -D USE_ITK   -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING  -D USE_LIBDAI -D USE_MAXFLOW -Wall -O3 -fopenmp -g -pg -D WITH_PNG -D WITH_OPENMP -D USE_REVERSE_INDEXING   -D USE_RAYS3D -D RAYS_MULTITHREADING   -D USE_ITK -O3 -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names     CMakeFiles/predict.dir/predict.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_struct/svm_struct_common.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_struct/svm_struct_learn.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_light/svm_common.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_light/svm_hideo.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_light/svm_learn.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_struct_api.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/svm_struct_learn_custom.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/constraint_set.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/label_cache.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/inference_globals.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/computeStats.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/globalStats.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/energyParam.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/inference.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/graphInference.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/gi_ICM.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/gi_max.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/gi_martingale.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/gi_MF.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/gi_sampling.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/gi_libDAI.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/gi_maxflow.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/BOF.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/colormap.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/Config.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/Feature.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Cluster.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_ColorHistogram.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Combo.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Gaussian.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Glcm.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Histogram.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_LoadFromFile.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_OrientedHistogram.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Position.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Precomputed.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Test.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/Histogram.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/HistogramND.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/oSVM.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/PixelData.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/Slice3d.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/Slice.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/Slice_P.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/SliceData.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/StatModel.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/Supernode.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/utils.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/libsvm-3.0/svm.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_3dRays.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_CannyStats.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_Filter.o CMakeFiles/predict.dir/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/core/F_GradientStats.o  -o predict  -L/Users/monso/code/InsightToolkit-3.20.1/build/bin  -L/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib  -L/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/3rdparty/lib  -L/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/slic/build  -L/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/rays3d/build  -L/Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/libDAI024/build  /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_contrib.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_stitching.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_nonfree.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_ocl.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_superres.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_ts.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_videostab.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_gpu.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_legacy.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_ml.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_objdetect.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_photo.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_video.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_features2d.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/3rdparty/lib/libIlmImf.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/3rdparty/lib/liblibjasper.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/3rdparty/lib/liblibtiff.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/3rdparty/lib/liblibpng.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_flann.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/opencv/build/3rdparty/lib/libzlib.a -lstdc++ -framework OpenCL -framework Cocoa -framework QTKit -framework QuartzCore -framework AppKit /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/slic/build/libsupervoxel.a -lITKIO -lITKStatistics /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/rays3d/build/librays3d.a /Users/monso/code/superpixels/branches/porting/lib/libDAI024/build/libdai.a -lITKNrrdIO -litkgdcm -litkjpeg12 -litkjpeg16 -litkopenjpeg -framework System -litkpng -litktiff -litkjpeg8 -lITKSpatialObject -lITKMetaIO -lITKDICOMParser -lITKEXPAT -lITKniftiio -lITKznz -litkzlib -lITKCommon -lm -litksys -litkvnl_inst -litkvnl_algo -litkvnl -litkvcl -litkv3p_lsqr -litkNetlibSlatec -litkv3p_netlib -lm
```

Any idea why, in Mac, the symbols are added on two different objects?

Comment: The OSX compiler/linker does the same stuff as the Linux/Windows equivalents.  Please list these duplicate symbols and show the complete linker command line.  While you are doing this there is a 40% chance you will solve this yourself...

Comment: Possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743803/c-linker-lack-of-duplicate-symbols  I would expect similar behavior on Mac OS X and Linus.  If one of them was going to differ, I'd expect it to be Windows because there are some fundamental differences in how unix-based linkers search for resolution.

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm guessing I'm in the 60%.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Agreed, Mac an Linux differ which is weird. I've checked the related question; in my case, I believe the same code (maxflow) is included in two different objects. I believe there's no actual code duplication.

Comment: OK cool; we're going to need to see the duplicate `maxflow::Graph<int, int, int>::add_tweights(int, int, int)` methods from `svm_struct_api.cpp` and `inference.cpp`.  The duplicate symbols looks like a template method so we probably need to see the header it's declared in as well.

Comment: Also read the accepted answer here and check you comply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318915/g-duplicate-symbol-error-when-working-with-templates-noob-question

Comment: @trojanfoe Thank you for your time trojanfoe. I've noticed svm_struct_api.c is a c file (!). However, none of the colliding objects define the add_tweights, so I did a grep on the whole repo and there are other definitions, I'll check if other definitions are linked by the project. Yet, the point still stands, why does Mac spit out an error while the others don't is a mistery to me.
Regarding the other comment, add_tweights is defined as an inline function on a graph.h header, so I would comply. I'll check if that's effectivelly the one included.

Comment: Well if you're using the Apple-supplied GNU compiler then it's going to be version 4.2.1 which is a long way from 4.6 you use under Linux.  I would look towards using the Xcode command line tools with clang 4.

Comment: @trojandoe I'm using gcc47 from MacPorts

Comment: OK; an important detail that should have been mentioned.

Comment: There's no compile lines, only the link line. Show your compile lines for `svm_struct_api` and `inference` from all three systems.

Comment: @n.m. I've added two compiling lines and the linking lines for Linux and Mac. I had to strip out part of the includes as I was reaching the SO character limit.

Comment: @trojanfoe Ok I checked, there's only one declaration of `::add_tweights`, so it seems that its code is getting included in two different objects that collide when linked afterwards. Any idea on how to allow `-z multidefs` with `g++`? I'm starting to get frustrated...

Comment: Err, sorry I've no idea.

Comment: add_tweights is a template. It should normally be in a header file. It should not, by itself, result in multiply defined symbols. Try to isolate the problem and create a minimal example. Also note that C language files should not be compiled with g++, as this command treats all source files as C++ which may create some nasty surprises.

Comment: @quimnuss I met exactly the same problem with you! I'm also using this maxflow package! WOuld you please tell me how did u solve the problem?

Comment: @spacegoing Uh... sorry spacegoing! i've long moved past this (2013!) I can't even remember if I solved the issue and I don't own a mac anymore to test it. You could give it a try https://github.com/quimnuss/graphCuts and the more elaborate https://github.com/alucchi/structured_prediction_for_segmentation

Comment: @quimnuss Lol. Thank you for your reply:D

Comment: @spacegoing I do believe we solved the issue thought. Good luck!